# Disabling and Reenabling Form Submit with JQuery in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that allows users to leave a comment.  Here is my submit action:

```
 <%= semantic_form_for([@project, step, step.comment_threads.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
    <%= f.actions do %>
         <%= f.action :submit, :label=>"Comment", :button_html => {:class=> "btn btn-small btn-primary commentSubmit", :disable_with => "Comment"} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I disable the form submit if the user tries to submit an empty comment.  But I can't get it to be re-enabled after the user enters text in the comment box. (When I click the comment button, the form doesn't get submitted). This is my javascript:

```
$('.commentSubmit').click(function(){
  var comment = $(this).parents('form').children('.field').find('textarea').val();
  console.log('comment: ' + comment);
  if(comment.length == 0){
    alert('Cannot post an empty comment');
    $(this).parents('form').submit(false);
  }else{
    console.log('submitting form');
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
  }     

});
```

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing is returning false if the user tries to submit the form with an empty comment.  It worked perfectly for me!

```
$('form.comment').submit(function(){
  var comment = $(this).children('.field').find('textarea').val();
  if(comment.length == 0){
    alert('Cannot post an empty comment');
    return false;
  }else{
    $(this).find('.commentSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use an `keyup` (or some other listener) to  enable the button once text is in the box.

See: [jQuery disable/enable submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button) or [jQuery enable/disble button depending on input field empty or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140303/jquery-enable-disble-button-depending-on-input-field-empty-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener for keyup instead of validating on click.

Set the submit button to disabled=true, then add:

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', function(event){
  if event.target.val().length > 0 {
    $('.commentSubmit').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.commentSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

This has the added benefit of re-disabling when they delete a comment.